# EF Core - ThenInclude() on collection with polymorphic elements

Tags: polymorphism, entity-framework-core, tph

I am trying to eager load properties from elements of a collection which itself is a property of another class. The elements of the collection are polymorphic, not sharing the properties I am trying to include, and tracked in the DB via TPH (Table-per-Hierachry). When I try to eager load them an exception is thrown stating that the base class does not contain the requested property.

I have an abstract base class `Base` and two derived classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`. `Base` has been configured for TPH like this

```
internal static void Configure(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // Get the EntityTypeBuilder from the given ModelBuilder
    EntityTypeBuilder<Base> entityBuilder = builder.Entity<Base>();

    // Configure TPH
    entityBuilder.ToTable("Bases").HasDiscriminator<int>("DerivedType")
                 .HasValue<DerivedA>(0)
                 .HasValue<DerivedB>(1);
}
```

Furthermore I have a class `ToBeLoaded` with a property `public ICollection<Base> Bases {get; set; }` which does contain both `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`. I am expecting EF Core to be able to handle this. Am I wrong with that?

The [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#include-on-derived-types) say I can use `as` or a direct cast within `ThenInclude()` like I do in my extension method.

```
public static IQueryable<ToBeLoaded> LoadRelated(this DbSet<ToBeLoaded> toBeLoadedSet)
{
    return toBeLoadedSet.Include(tbl => tbl.Bases)
                               .ThenInclude(b => (b as DerivedA).PropA)
                               .Include(tbl => tbl.Bases)
                               .ThenInclude(b => (b as DerviedB).PropB);
}
```

When then calling `context.ToBeLoadedSet.LoadRelated.ToList();` the following exception is thrown

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'PropA' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Base'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.'
```

I already tried to use the other ways to achieve this suggested in the docs, namely direct cast and the `Include(string)` method.
I am aware that this is somewhat different from the example in the docs, but that is the closest thing to my situation I could find.

Is this even theoretically possible using the Include interface or should I just try to use [RawSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after writing the whole question up I tried one more thing. Just including `Bases` like `toBeLoadedSet.Include(tbl => tbl.Bases)`. For some reason I thought I tried this before and then `PropA` and `ProbB` where `null`, but just wanted to be sure.

Since it's there now anyways and it might prevent someone else from wasting their time, I will just post it. Thanks for being my rubber duck.

To be clear, the `LoadRelated` method looks like this now

```
public static IQueryable<ToBeLoaded> LoadRelated(this DbSet<ToBeLoaded> toBeLoadedSet)
{
    return toBeLoadedSet.Include(tbl => tbl.Bases);
}
```